# Sum Variable-Length Week's Expenses

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an excel spreadsheet for someone else without much Excel experience. It's a relatively basic expense spreadsheet, with rows being a given date's expenses, and columns being the types of expenses and their amounts. I'd like to automate as much as possible with formulas or VBA.

Here is an example:

[image: A table formatted as described above]

I understand how to sum up all expenditures in the table, but I'd also like to break them down on a week-by-week basis. The table will probably be added to rather infrequently, so there will be missing days. I'm not sure how to sum the weekly totals when there may be any number of entries for a given week.

For the example above, I'd like to have a column somewhere on the spreadsheet that has Week 1's sum (1/4/2015 and 1/5/2015) as one entry, and Week 2's sum (1/14/2015 and 1/16/2015) as a second entry.

[image: A table summing up the weekly expenditures]

Is this possible to automate with a formula or script?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a pivottable ("Insert" ribbon, "PivotTable" button on left)